# tsql query soap get first element name after s:Body

Tags: sql, t-sql, xpath, xml-namespaces

I have a soap XML like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Body u:Id="_2">
        <TestRecord xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        </TestRecord>
   </s:Body>
 </s:Envelope>
```

how can i use local-name syntax to get the first element name after s:Body ?

it should give me TestRecord.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//s:Body` returns all `s:Body` nodes and `//s:Body/*` returns all child nodes to all `s:Body` nodes. Add the predicate `[1]` and you will get the first child node of a `s:Body` node in the document. Use that as a parameter to the function `local-name()`.

```
declare @X xml;

set @X = '
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
            xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Body u:Id="_2">
    <TestRecord xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"></TestRecord>
    <TestRecord1 xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"></TestRecord1>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>';

 with xmlnamespaces ('http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' as s)
 select @x.value('local-name((//s:Body/*)[1])', 'varchar(100)');
```

Comment: Thank you :) Accepted for the explanation :), @tomislav_tv's solution works too

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get it like this:

```
DECLARE @x XML

SET @x = '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Body u:Id="_2">
        <TestRecord xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        </TestRecord>
   </s:Body>
 </s:Envelope>'

 ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' AS s)
 SELECT  X.Y.value('(fn:local-name(.))[1]','varchar(max)')
 FROM @x.nodes('/s:Envelope/s:Body/*') X(Y)
```

The trick is to specify the namespace with WITH XMLNAMESPACES and to use fn:local-name.